# Android crash with ChooserActivity

Tags: android

I do some manipulation with data in background thread and after I want to ask user to choose corresponded activity to process result:

```
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser( intent, getString( R.string.select_application_for, intent.getData() ) );
chooserIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents.toArray( new Parcelable[ intents.size() ] ) );
startActivity( chooserIntent );
```

However I always get crash with next StackTrace:

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I comment line:

```
chooserIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents.toArray( new Parcelable[ intents.size() ] ) );
```

crash disappears, but this is not what I want to do.

I wonder if someone already solved this puzzle.

Comment: Take a look this is Android class. And yes, it has `super.onCreate()`

Comment: Sorry, it was a useless thing to ask. From the source, it looks like `!(pa[i] instanceof Intent)` is evaluating to true for one or more of your intents, `pa` being `intents.toArray( new Parcelable[ intents.size() ] )`. Can you use `Log` statements to confirm that items in `intents` do pass `intents.get(i) instanceof Intent`?

Comment: You're right. My bad eyes. Could you submit answer and I will accept it

Comment: Anyway, looking at the source code this crash looks like a bug in the framework. I don't see the point of returning without calling `super.onCreate()`. It seems designed to only display a warning, but the developer may have forgotten that `super.onCreate()` is called at the end of this method and not at the beginning as it's usually the case.

Comment: @Dalmas Why is this a bug? The framework is (kind of) doing your work for you. If an object of type X is expected, and you provide an object of type Y, should that be acceptable?

Comment: @user2558882 But why would there be a call to `finish();` just before crashing the app? This looks a bit weird.

Comment: @Dalmas I see what you mean. But, `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, target, title, initialIntents, null, false)` call requires `initialIntents` which in OP's case wasn't being created successfully. Hence, calling finish() and returning, kind of makes sense. It's definitely weird though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was resolved in the following comment:

From the source, it looks like !(pa[i] instanceof Intent) is evaluating to true for one or more of your intents, pa being intents.toArray( new Parcelable[ intents.size() ] ). Can you use Log statements to confirm that items in intents do pass intents.get(i) instanceof Intent?

Source:

```
public class  [More ...] ChooserActivity extends ResolverActivity {
    @Override
    protected void  [More ...] onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ....
    ....

    Parcelable[] pa = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS);
        Intent[] initialIntents = null;
        if (pa != null) {
            initialIntents = new Intent[pa.length];
            for (int i=0; i<pa.length; i++) {

                // The check for if-statement is evaluating to `true`
                if (!(pa[i] instanceof Intent)) {
                    Log.w("ChooseActivity", "Initial intent #" + i
                        + " not an Intent: " + pa[i]);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
                initialIntents[i] = (Intent)pa[i];
            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, target, title, initialIntents, false);
    }
```